# How to dynamically update a var from a parallel component in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a 'views' page that imports two components, one of which is a NavBar that will display a loading animation until the other component is fully loaded in.

The way I'm trying to accomplish this, is I am trying to define a 'loading' var in the view, pass that var into the NavBar AND releases components.  IF I change the loading to false from the releases component that should propagate over to the NavBar (to stop the loading animation).

views/Release.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NavBar v-bind:loading="this.loading"></NavBar>
    <div id="vue-main">
      <h1><b>Releases</b></h1>
      <Releases v-bind:loading="this.loading"></Releases>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Releases from "../components/Releases.vue";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar.vue";

export default {
  name: "releases",
  data () {
    return {
      loading: 'loading'
    }
  },
  components: {
    NavBar,
    Releases,
  }
};
</script>
```

components/NavBar.vue

```
<template>
<div>
  <div id="nav">
    <a href='/link1'>Link 1</a>
    <a href='/link2'>Link 2</a>
    <a href='/link3'>Link 3</a>
    <pulse-loader :loading="this.loading"></pulse-loader>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import PulseLoader from 'vue-spinner/src/PulseLoader.vue';
export default {
  name: 'NavBar',
  props: ['loading'],
  components: {
    PulseLoader
  },
};
</script>
```

I have left out Releases.vue from this post for brevity, but no matter where I set

```
this.loading=false
```

It does not seem to propagate over to NavBar component.
What am I doing wrong here?  Not sure If I need to use $emit for something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should NOT modify the prop `loading` from `Releases.vue`.

In `Releases.vue` when data loaded, call `$emit`:

```
this.loadReleases()
  .then(() => {
    // Your logic.
    this.$emit('loaded', true);
  });
```

In the view `Release.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NavBar :loading="loading"></NavBar>
    <div id="vue-main">
      <h1><b>Releases</b></h1>
      <Releases @loaded="updateLoading"></Releases>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Releases from "../components/Releases.vue";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar.vue";

export default {
  name: "releases",
  data () {
    return {
      loading: true,
    }
  },
  components: {
    NavBar,
    Releases,
  },
  methods: {
    updateLoading(val) {
      this.loading = !val; // loading = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Please, use `:` instead of `v-bind`, `@` instead of `v-on` for making the code clear. And it's no need to use `this` on the template.**

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `this` in your templates.

```
<NavBar v-bind:loading="loading"></NavBar>
    <div id="vue-main">
      <h1><b>Releases</b></h1>
      <Releases v-bind:loading="loading"></Releases>
      <Footer></Footer>


<pulse-loader :loading="loading"></pulse-loader>
```

In fact, eveything in the template refers to `this` component, and you can't refer to anything else directly from the template.

`$emit` is for sending data up to the parent, and the main use case for that is to tell the parent to update a property that then flows back down to the component.  Your use case is updating children, and using v-bind is appropriate, as the NavBar *owns* the data.